# How to fix UWP Apps got Application Hang error?

Tags: uwp

Recently I upgrade my win10 to 1909 with OS build 18363.1377. Sometimes the UWP APPS can' be launched normally. And then I checked the windows error logs in event viewer, the error is: The program XXXX.exe version 1.0.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel. Hang type: Cross-thread. And all the system build in UWP apps also got this error, like Camera/Maps.

I must reboot my device to fix it temporally.

My question is what should I do I can fix it permanently? Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Does your app work in previous  OS version  well?

Comment: Yes, never happened in previous OS.

Comment: For this, we suggest you update to latest OS version and test again. It does not look like uwp problem.

Comment: Yes, understood. I will ask my teammates rebuild it later if no good solution to solve it.

Comment: Ok, please let me know the result.

Comment: Unfortunately, after rebuilding the device the issue persist. we already invited Microsoft professor help us to investigate the issue. Thank you.